# How can post form raw data as parameters in Alamofire request?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

How to make post request in swift using alamofire with request body of raw json data. Following is the raw data.

{"KeyValue": "{CustomerID':9,Password':test}"}

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I post `JSON raw data` like following

```
let userId: String = "jakir"
let userPassword: String = "jakir123"

let js = "{\"userId\":\"\(userId)\",\"userPassword\":\"\(userPassword)\"}"
let parameters: Parameters = ["jsonRequest": "\(js)"]

Alamofire.request("https://abcd.com/login", method: .post, parameters: getParameters(json: js),headers: ApiEndPoint.ProductionServer.headers)
            .responseJSON { response in
                proccessedResponse(response: response){ json in
                     completion(json)
                }
          }
```

NOTE: I used `Alamofire ~> 4.7`

Answer (score 0):

```
      Alamofire.request( url, method: .post , parameters: parameters, encoding:  JSONEncoding.default ,headers:nil).responseJSON{
            response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                   // your code of putting data in form of NSDictionary
                    self.stopProgress()

                }else{
                       self.stopProgress()

                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                   self.stopProgress()
            }
        }

// put url in place of url above in parameter.
// progress in SVHUDProgress it's a pod
// you can also use SwiftyJson with it, it would be more helpful for parsing
```